# How to make a component show different content according to the situation?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I have a component that will be used to display a message in one section of my website, but I want to reuse it to display messages in other sections. However, in the first case, the content has only a title and a paragraph, and in the other part the content has more than one title and more than one content. Is there a better way to accomplish this? The way I did it works, but I don't know if it's ideal.

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="raleway">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet'>
    <section>
        <Message title="Just a title" messageContent="Just a message"/>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Message from "./components/Message.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Message,
  },
};
</script>

<style>
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #3B3B3B;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
}

</style>
```

Component

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
      <section>
        <h2>{{title}}</h2>
        <p>{{messageContent}}</p>
        <h2>{{title2}}</h2>
      </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Message',
  props: {
    title: String,
    messageContent: String,
    title2: String,
    messageContent2: String,
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.container{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 15em;
    color: #FFF;
    width: 82%;
}

.container h2{
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}

.container p{
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-top: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.container p{
    font-size: 1.33em;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 580px) {
.container{
    margin-top: 12em;
}
.container h2{
    font-size: 1.17em;
}
.container p{
    font-size: 1em;
}
}
</style>
```

Comment: is there any reason you don't use slots? I think it might help

Comment: No, I'm new with Vue so I didn't know this way, but it was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options.
One is using array of titles and messages as props values.

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <section>
      <h2 v-for="(title, i) in titles">{{ title }}</h2>
      <p v-for="(messageContent, i) in messageContents">{{ messageContent }}</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Message',
  props: {
    titles: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    },
    messageContents: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

And use this `MessageContent` component like below.

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="raleway">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet'>
    <section>
      <Message :titles="['Title 1', 'Title 2']" :messageContents="['message 1', 'message 2']"/>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Message from "./components/Message.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Message,
  },
};
</script>
```

The second option is to use slot. It can be more flexible but depends what the `Message` component looks like.

Comment: The second option was very helpful, thanks!